# How to add click listener to textview in onBindHeaderViewHolder() method?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want open a CalenderActivity on click of textview in recyclerView. In adapter class I extend **StickyRecyclerHeadersAdapter**. I have written below code in my **onBindHeaderViewHolder** method but it won't work, please any solutions will be helpful. Thanks

**My Code:**

```
override fun onCreateHeaderViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?): HeaderViewHolder {
        val itemHeaderBinding =
            ItemTimelineHeaderBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
        return HeaderViewHolder(itemHeaderBinding)
}

class HeaderViewHolder(val itemHeaderBinding: ItemTimelineHeaderBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemHeaderBinding.root)

override fun getHeaderId(position: Int): Long {
     return timelineParentModelArrayList!![position].timelineDateHeader
}

override fun onBindHeaderViewHolder(holder: HeaderViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val timelinedAt = "12 JAN 2021"

        holder.itemHeaderBinding.apply {
            tvDate.text = timelinedAt

            tvDate.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context, CalenderActivity::class.java)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
}
```

but this won't work?

Comment: Have you tried registering the listener in the ViewHolder's constructor ??

Comment: @Noah no, how to do that?

Comment: Where is the context initialization?

Answer (score 0):

I use Java but my little knowledge of Kotlin, use this to register the listener in the constructor.

```
   class HeaderViewHolder(val itemHeaderBinding: ItemTimelineHeaderBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemHeaderBinding.root)
    {
         holder.itemHeaderBinding.apply {
            tvDate.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(context, CalenderActivity::class.java)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

In case the syntax is wrong, this is how I would have implemented it in Java.

```
public class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public HeaderViewHolder (ItemTimelineHeaderBinding itemHeaderBinding){
         itemHeaderBinding.tvDate.setOnClickListener(v -> {  });
   }

}
```

Comment: tried this, but not working